# Accessing model value for if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to make an if statement in the controller that accesses a value from my model. For example, if I am trying to access this radio button value from my model, how would I do it?

```
[Required] public bool radbutton { get; set; }.
```

At the top, I tried `'using PasswordTool.Models'`.

Then inside my method:

```
if(PasswordModel.radbutton) 
                           //do something
```

**PasswordModel**

```
namespace PasswordTool.Models
{
    public class PasswordModel
    {
        [Required] public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required] public bool RadioButton { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expect the PasswordModel.radbutton to access the value of the radio button in the model, but intellisense isn't even registering that it exists.

Comment: could you post code for your method?

Comment: you need an instance of the model.

Comment: read this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller it will provide you the basic idea about how to use the model in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there **heisenberg3481**,

Welcome to StackOverflow!

To pass `Model` values from the `View` you would need to do the following:

```
@model PasswordModel

// - If the bellow doesn't work try removing the 'Controller' in "MemberController" - //
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetPassword", "MemberController")) 
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password);
    Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.RadioButton);

    <button type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
}
```

Then in your controller you can retrieve the data like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPassword (PasswordModel objModel)
{
    if (objModel.RadioButton) {
        // Execute action
    }

    return View();
}
```